# Using TUN\TAP virtual interfaces manually

Tags: networking, protocols, vpn, tunnel

I can not find any information on how TUN/TAP works.  I would like to create a simple tunnel between two hosts and establish a virtual address space between them (similar to a GRE tunnel).  I do not want any encryption, or any VPN.

My issue is that I don't even know what protocol TUN speaks.  When a tunnel interface is created and data is sent to the other end what protocol is the listening "tun server" (tunnel endpoint) speaking and what port are you connecting to?

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to the [kernel document for tun/tap](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt) for the introduction and the [vtun project](http://vtun.sourceforge.net/) for a working example of using tun/tap to create tunnels.